# Что означает строка new Class<?>[] { int.class }?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Вот строка:

```
Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[] { int.class };
```

Как я понимаю мы имеем ссылку paramTypes, которая ссылается на масив типа "`Class<?>`". Далее мы инициализируем массив `new Class<?>[]`, а что делает `{ int.class }`?

Comment: это элемент в срзданном массиве

Comment: Таким образом указываются типы параметров метода, который вы хотите использовать посредством рефлексии, в данном случае метод принимает один параметр типа `int`, как и сказал _Grundy_.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, вы б это в виде ответа опубликовали б)

Answer (score 3):

Это один из способов инициализации массива (т.е. по аналогии: `int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3};`), т.е. в вашем случае массив инициализируется элементами, которые представляют собой типы параметров.
Подробнее о способах инициализации массива можете посмотреть [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/array.php).

Таким образом (посредством элементов массива) указываются типы параметров метода, который вы можете вызвать посредством рефлексии. В вашем случае метод принимает один параметр, который имеет тип `int`.
Подробнее об этом можете посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) или [здесь](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-reflection-api).

---

Например:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class ReflectionClass
{
    private void privateMethod(int parm)
    {
        System.out.println("Call method with int parm == " + parm + " from class " + this.getClass().toString());
    }
}

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ReflectionClass obj = new ReflectionClass();

            Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{ int.class }; // на самом деле можно писать просто Class вместо Class<?>
            Method privateMethod = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("privateMethod", paramTypes);

            int parmValue = 1;
            privateMethod.setAccessible(true);
            privateMethod.invoke(obj, parmValue);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```